# Spring @Cacheable for methods with same signature

Tags: java, spring, caching

I have a Spring bean that has a couple of finders with the same signature, like this:

```
@Cacheable
public Player findById(int id) {
    // query player by id
    return player;
}

@Cacheable
public Player findByRank(int rank) {
    // query player by rank
    return  player;
}
```

The @Cacheable annotation treats both methods equal so this messes up the cache. Is there a way to tell Spring that the keys for those methods are not the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try this? Not sure whether it works..

```
@Cacheable(value = "playerId")
public Player findById(int id) {
    // query player by id
    return player;
}

@Cacheable(value = "playerRank")
public Player findByRank(int rank) {
    // query player by rank
    return  player;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works! I was hoping for a fool-proof solution, but this solves the problem for now.